# Copying data from python list to clipboard

Tags: python, sap-gui

I am beating my head against a wall. I have a python script that calls an SAP GUI script through a shell command.  That part works great, once the `returns.xlsx` is generated, I use `openpyxl` to create a list from the values in column A. From there I try to append the list to the clipboard so I can paste it via a second SAP GUI script.  For some reason when I try to paste in excel after the script completes, Excel throws an error window:

> Microsoft Excel cannot paste data

Full script below:

```
from subprocess import call
import warnings
import win32gui
import os
import time
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from Tkinter import Tk
import wx
import pyautogui


warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
filePath = os.path.expanduser("~\Desktop\\")
app = wx.App() 
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1)


############## Start and stop dates
dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(frame, 'Enter Start Date','Start Date')
dlg.SetValue("mm/dd/YYYY")
if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:             
    startDate = dlg.GetValue()
dlg.Destroy()

dlg2 = wx.TextEntryDialog(frame, 'Enter End Date','End Date')
dlg2.SetValue("mm/dd/YYYY")
if dlg2.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
    endDate = dlg2.GetValue()
dlg2.Destroy()
#############


############################Functions for getting the window names and copying data to the clip board
def GetWindowName():
    winName=win32gui.GetWindowText (win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())
    return winName

def CopytoClip(clipList):

    r = Tk()
    r.withdraw()
    r.clipboard_clear()
    for item in clipList:           
        
        r.clipboard_append(item)
        r.clipboard_append("\n")
    r.update()
    r.destroy()

############################


###################SAP GUI Shell Commands
command =  'guixt.exe "Input=V[MYDATE]:%s;V[END_DATE]:%s;OK: process=C:\guixt\scripts\\RetReport2.txt"' %(startDate, endDate)
call(command, shell = True, cwd = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\\')
###################



################################Waiting for the save as window and saving the file as retuns.xlsx on the desktop
winName = "nothing"
while winName != "Save As":
    winName = GetWindowName()
    time.sleep(1)
retFile = filePath + 'returns.XLSX'
pyautogui.typewrite(retFile)
pyautogui.press('enter')
################################

###############Waiting for the file to auto open
winName = "nothing"
while winName != "returns.XLSX - Excel":
    winName = GetWindowName()
    time.sleep(2)
################################

##############################Create the list from column A and append to clipboard
salesOrders = []
wbSales = load_workbook(filename = retFile)
wsSales = wbSales['Sheet1']
for row in wsSales.iter_rows('A:A', row_offset = 1):
    for cell in row:
        try:
            salesOrders.append(int(cell.value))
        except TypeError:
            pass
        
CopytoClip(salesOrders)
#################################
```

Now if I use the "returns.xlsx" created above in the following short script that I cut from the above script... the clipboard is full.

**Can anyone help figure out why the clipboard will not work in the full script?**

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from tkinter import *
import time
import os


filePath = os.path.expanduser("~\Desktop\\")
retFile = filePath + 'returns.XLSX'


def CopytoClip(clipList):
 
    r = Tk()
    r.withdraw()
    r.clipboard_clear()
    for item in clipList:
         
        r.clipboard_append(item)
        r.clipboard_append("\n")
    r.update()
    r.destroy()


salesOrders = []
wbSales = load_workbook(filename = retFile)
wsSales = wbSales['Sheet1']
for row in wsSales.iter_rows('A:A', row_offset = 1):
    for cell in row:
        try:
            salesOrders.append(int(cell.value))
        except TypeError:
            pass
        
CopytoClip(salesOrders)
```

Comment: Can you paste it into e.g. notepad? What if you double click on an Excel cell first?

Comment: still no dice, it seems like the clipboard is empty.  But again if I run the second script, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just print the second arguments to then pipe the params ?

```
print(saleOrders)
```

And from the command line :

```
python firstscript.py whateverparamineed | secondscript
```

Comment: That could work... I will try that. Right now, I just used pyautogui to press Ctrl+C when the window opens.